# Is there a way to tell if an ES6 promise is fulfilled/rejected/resolved?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm used to Dojo promises, where I can just do the following:

```
promise.isFulfilled();
promise.isResolved();
promise.isRejected();
```

Is there a way to determine if an ES6 promise is fulfilled, resolved, or rejected? If not, is there a way to fill in that functionality using `Object.defineProperty(Promise.prototype, ...)`?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you should be able to access the state and resolve value https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-properties-of-promise-instances

Comment: The intent of internal slots, of the form `[[<name>]]` is there is no way to access them as they are specification details that might not actually exist in the implementation. They are used to describe the behavior of the spec, not the runtime layout of the actual object; so, no you can't access the internal state.

Comment: Why was this question marked a duplicate? This is the question with the better actual response. The other just tells you what you can't do and doesn't provide any hint as to a solution. I think the other question/answer is useless for actually solving the posed problem.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

They are not part of the specification nor is there a standard way of accessing them that you could use to get the internal state of the promise to construct a polyfill. However, you can convert any standard promise into one that has these values by creating a wrapper,

```
function MakeQueryablePromise(promise) {
    // Don't create a wrapper for promises that can already be queried.
    if (promise.isResolved) return promise;
    
    var isResolved = false;
    var isRejected = false;

    // Observe the promise, saving the fulfillment in a closure scope.
    var result = promise.then(
       function(v) { isResolved = true; return v; }, 
       function(e) { isRejected = true; throw e; });
    result.isFulfilled = function() { return isResolved || isRejected; };
    result.isResolved = function() { return isResolved; }
    result.isRejected = function() { return isRejected; }
    return result;
}
```

This doesn't affect all promises, as modifying the prototype would, but it does allow you to convert a promise into a promise that exposes it state.

Comment: This seems to be wrong. Your implementation returns false for isResolved when promise is rejected. I would set isFulfilled in the fulfill callback and then calculate isResolved based on either isFulfilled or isRejected being set. However the simplest way is to set isResolved in both callbacks alongside respective isFulfilled and isRejected values.

Comment: I believe the implementation, as far as it goes, is correct, at least according to the dojo documentation: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/promise/Promise.html

Comment: Indeed your [terminology](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29268569/1048572) seems to be messed up. You should use `isSettled`, `isFulfilled` and `isRejected`.

Comment: The question is about simulating Dojo with a standard promise and the terminology is theirs, not mine.

Comment: This always returns false for me in all of the 3 functions...

Comment: Note that this will not work synchronously, not even for already resolved promises. E.g., `console.log(MakeQuerablePromise(Promise.resolve(777)).isResolved())` gives `false`.