# How can I synchronously determine a JavaScript Promise's state?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a pure JavaScript Promise (built-in implementation or poly-fill):

`var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { /* ... */ });`

From the [specification](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-promise-objects), a Promise can be one of:

- 'settled' and 'resolved'
- 'settled' and 'rejected'
- 'pending'

I have a use case where I wish to interrogate the Promise synchronously and determine:

- is the Promise settled?
- if so, is the Promise resolved?

I know that I can use [`#then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to schedule work to be performed asynchronously after the Promise changes state. I am NOT asking how to do this.

This question is specifically about **synchronous interrogation of a Promise's state**. How can I achieve this?

Comment: set a property on the promise which can be seen from outside, and use then() to change the property.

Comment: @jokeyrhyme fwiw,  v8 source https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/promise.js?r=18113 see `var promiseStatus = NEW_PRIVATE("Promise#status");` , `PromiseSet` function at `SET_PRIVATE(promise, promiseStatus, status);`

Comment: Here we go: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/how-can-i-synchronously-determine-a-javascript-promise-s-state

Comment: It seems odd that if you do const a = Promise.resolve('baz'); console.log(a); and look in Chrome console, you see Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: "baz"} proto : Promise [[PromiseStatus]] : "resolved" [[PromiseValue]] : "baz" and people claim it can't be done. How is Chrome doing it? (was doing this in a Plunker with Angular http://plnkr.co/edit/IPIWgLJKQStI5ubXmcsF

Comment: Using node v11.12.0 console.log will show promise state. E.G. `console.log(Promise.new((resolve, reject) => {})` => `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: GitHub issue about adding such feature to Node.js: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40054

Comment: here is a very deep explanation on how promises change their state https://intspirit.medium.com/deep-deep-deep-into-promises-8dc72e86487a

Answer (score 128, accepted):

**No such synchronous inspection API exists for native JavaScript promises.** It is impossible to do this with native promises. The specification does not specify such a method.

Userland libraries can do this, and if you're targeting a specific engine (like v8) and have access to *platform code* (that is, you can write code in *core*) then you can use specific tools (like private symbols) to achieve this. That's super specific though and not in userland.

Comment: Note: I honestly believe the use cases for synchronous inspection are few and very rare, if you share your concrete use case _in a new question_ asking how to achieve it without synchronous inspection - I'll give answering it a shot if someone won't beat me to it :)

Comment: Even if the use cases are rare, what harm would including something like this do? I would need a status check like this to see if the previous job was finished and if I can request another job. And I can't just set an external variable because the object has the potential to change owners without notice. What's more irritating is I can SEE Node.js has access to this information because it shows it to me when I inspect it, but there's no way to get at it besides parsing strings??

Comment: @Tustin2121 if you're using Node you can just use bluebird and get a much richer API with synchronous inspection.

Comment: So we must throw away native promises as they're impractical and always use bluebird. Great news! How do I propose native promises to become deprecated and thrown out of node engine?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, And what's wrong with `Promise.race`?

Comment: Lots of things, we should have specced `.any` instead and made a mistake because Mark insisted. For one, `Promise.race([])` is a forever pending promise (and not an error), you typically want the first _successful_ promise and not just the first promise. Anyway, that's not really relevant to the question asked - OP asked about synchronous inspection and not about `.race` and its many shortcomings.

Comment: @user619271 Are you saying native promises are impractical because they lack synchronous inspection?

Comment: @JLRishe Yes. Everything that lacks basic debugging options is impractical unless it's an asm code.

Comment: @user619271 There are plenty of ways to debug promises. Just because they can't be debugged in the way you want to debug them doesn't make them impractical. I've been working with promises for years and never had a need to synchronously obtain a promise's state. So the claim "we must throw away native promises" is tosh.

Comment: @JLRishe please have this discussion in a chat room. (promises can be synchronously inspected in the debugger, by the way).

Comment: While it's good to know the actual spec, this answer does NOTHING to point folks at a useful solution other than say "use this library". Sure, that library is useful if you want to pull it in, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485545/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-an-es6-promise-is-fulfilled-rejected-resolved has a solution that works without having to add a library.

Comment: @Akrikos that answer does't let you synchronously inspect the state of a promise  - For example `MakeQueryablePromise(Promise.resolve(3)).isResolved` is false but the promise is quite obviously resolved. Not to mention that answer is also using the term "resolved" and "fulfilled" incorrectly. To do that that answer does you could just add a `.then` handler yourself - which completely misses the point of synchronous inspection.

Comment: what is "userland" ?

Comment: From a library and not from the core language - implemented by users of the platform and not the platform itself

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I tried using `process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails` and I used some nodejs API that returns promise and queried whether that promise is resolved in synchronous manner, but it always told me that promise is not resolved( Code is here https://pastebin.com/DewTs7Ff) even though answer usually comes in milliseconds. 

My question was do we need stack to be empty so that even internally promise is marked as resolved, I know then handler runs when stack is empty, but does  internally promise is marked as resolved only when stack is empty?

Comment: My other question is if it is marked as resolved when stack is empty, how am I able to add a debugger; statement and wait and when I inspect promise after waiting for a while with debugger still there, promise is resolved, even though still I have functions in stack.

Comment: Hi, open a new question?

Answer (score 112):

Nope, no sync API, but here's my version of the async `promiseState` (with help from @Matthijs):

```js
function promiseState(p) {
  const t = {};
  return Promise.race([p, t])
    .then(v => (v === t)? "pending" : "fulfilled", () => "rejected");
}

var a = Promise.resolve();
var b = Promise.reject();
var c = new Promise(() => {});

promiseState(a).then(state => console.log(state)); // fulfilled
promiseState(b).then(state => console.log(state)); // rejected
promiseState(c).then(state => console.log(state)); // pending
```

Comment: Is there a specific reasoning behind this construction? It seems unnecessarily complicated to me. As far as I can tell this works identically: `Promise.race([
      Promise.resolve(p).then(() => "fulfilled", () => "rejected"),
      Promise.resolve().then(() => "pending")
    ]);`

Although this seems safer to me: `const t = {};
    return Promise.race([p,t]).then(v => v === t ? "pending" : "fulfilled", () => "rejected")`

and avoids creating additional promises that persist as long as the original p is pending.

Comment: Thanks @Matthijs! I've simplified my answer.

Comment: +1 Came here looking for this exactly. Perfect example of an answer not answering the original question, but still being super useful to a lot of people landing here.

Comment: To save some future souls time, if the `Promise` global is the `ZoneAwarePromise` implementation from Angular and you are dealing with Promises returned from `async` functions in your DevTools, the logic here breaks. This appears to be because the `Promise.race` immediately resolves the returned `Promise` with the `t` value on the wrong event cycle. I worked around it by changing the second parameter from `t` to `(async function() { return t })()` which seemed to slow it down enough to behave as expected.

Comment: Is it better, use `const t = Symbol()`

Comment: @flyflydogdog can you elaborate on why the `Symbol` would be better choice?

Comment: It's not necessarily better, but `Symbol` is designed to be a unique value that doesn't collide with other values. However an empty object is also a unique value, so for this scenario it wouldn't make much of a difference. The main thing of symbols is that they can be used as unique object properties, whereas an object would be converted to the string key `"[object]"`. (1/2)

Comment: The main advantage in this scenario when swapping out `{}` for a symbol would be readability/debugging clarity. Symbols can contain a description which makes the code easier to read. `const pending = Symbol("pending")` then `Promise.race([promise, pending]).then(value => value === pending ? "pending" : "fulfilled", () => "rejected")` (2/2)

Answer (score 43):

[image]

[promise-status-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-status-async) does the trick. It is async but it does not use `then` to wait the promise to be resolved.

```
const {promiseStatus} = require('promise-status-async');
// ...
if (await promiseStatus(promise) === 'pending') {
    const idle = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        // can do some IDLE job meanwhile
    });
    return idle;
}
```

Comment: OP asked about how to do it synchronously though

Comment: @Klesun maybe this is a good enough solution for more people than just the OP, considering there is an already accepted answer?

Comment: But... but there are other questions that don't explicitly deny async solutions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294109/how-to-check-if-a-promise-is-pending) (naturally closed because there is no way a similar sounding problem may actually have different conditions, right, mods ^_^)

Comment: solution is very simple without any additional boilerplate code around my promises. so it is not a quite answer to OP but still the best workaround approach.

Comment: it matters just using the pure functions without any artifacts and side mutations on my promises which is pretty good <3

Answer (score 19):

You can make a race with Promise.resolve
It's not synchronous but happens now

```
function promiseState(p, isPending, isResolved, isRejected) {
  Promise.race([p, Promise.resolve('a value that p should not return')]).then(function(value) {
    if (value == 'a value that p should not return') {
      (typeof(isPending) === 'function') && isPending();
    }else {
      (typeof(isResolved) === 'function') && isResolved(value);
    }
  }, function(reason) {
    (typeof(isRejected) === 'function') && isRejected(reason);
  });
}
```

A little script for testing and  understand their meaning of asynchronously

```
var startTime = Date.now() - 100000;//padding trick "100001".slice(1) => 00001
function log(msg) {
  console.log((""+(Date.now() - startTime)).slice(1) + ' ' + msg);
  return msg;//for chaining promises
};

function prefix(pref) { return function (value) { log(pref + value); return value; };}

function delay(ms) {
  return function (value) {
    var startTime = Date.now();
    while(Date.now() - startTime < ms) {}
    return value;//for chaining promises
  };
}
setTimeout(log, 0,'timeOut 0 ms');
setTimeout(log, 100,'timeOut 100 ms');
setTimeout(log, 200,'timeOut 200 ms');

var p1 = Promise.resolve('One');
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { setTimeout(resolve, 100, "Two"); });
var p3 = Promise.reject("Three");

p3.catch(delay(200)).then(delay(100)).then(prefix('delayed L3 : '));

promiseState(p1, prefix('p1 Is Pending '), prefix('p1 Is Resolved '), prefix('p1 Is Rejected '));
promiseState(p2, prefix('p2 Is Pending '), prefix('p2 Is Resolved '), prefix('p2 Is Rejected '));
promiseState(p3, prefix('p3 Is Pending '), prefix('p3 Is Resolved '), prefix('p3 Is Rejected '));

p1.then(prefix('Level 1 : ')).then(prefix('Level 2 : ')).then(prefix('Level 3 : '));
p2.then(prefix('Level 1 : ')).then(prefix('Level 2 : ')).then(prefix('Level 3 : '));
p3.catch(prefix('Level 1 : ')).then(prefix('Level 2 : ')).then(prefix('Level 3 : '));
log('end of promises');
delay(100)();
log('end of script');
```

results with delay(0) (comment the while in delay)

```
00001 end of promises
00001 end of script
00001 Level 1 : One
00001 Level 1 : Three
00001 p1 Is Resolved One
00001 p2 Is Pending undefined
00001 p3 Is Rejected Three
00001 Level 2 : One
00001 Level 2 : Three
00001 delayed L3 : Three
00002 Level 3 : One
00002 Level 3 : Three
00006 timeOut 0 ms
00100 timeOut 100 ms
00100 Level 1 : Two
00100 Level 2 : Two
00101 Level 3 : Two
00189 timeOut 200 ms
```

and the results of this test with firefox(chrome keep the order)

```
00000 end of promises
00100 end of script
00300 Level 1 : One
00300 Level 1 : Three
00400 p1 Is Resolved One
00400 p2 Is Pending undefined
00400 p3 Is Rejected Three
00400 Level 2 : One
00400 Level 2 : Three
00400 delayed L3 : Three
00400 Level 3 : One
00400 Level 3 : Three
00406 timeOut 0 ms
00406 timeOut 100 ms
00406 timeOut 200 ms
00406 Level 1 : Two
00407 Level 2 : Two
00407 Level 3 : Two
```

promiseState make .race and .then : Level 2

Comment: Instead of `'a value that p should not return'`, use a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

Comment: @programmer5000 What is the benefit?

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst a `Symbol` would be a unique value, therefore you'd never have to guess what "value [...] p should not return." However, a reference to a specific object would work just as well.

Comment: Another pitfall I came across while implementing this is that it always loses to any of the composite Promises:
`Promise.race([Promise.any([Promise.resolve("expected winner")]), Promise.resolve("real winner")]);`

Answer (score 15):

in node, say [undocumented internal](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14038#issuecomment-312490451) `process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails(promise)`

```
> process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails(Promise.resolve({data: [1,2,3]}));
[ 1, { data: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } ]

> process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails(Promise.reject(new Error('no')));
[ 2, Error: no ]

> process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails(new Promise((resolve) => {}));
[ 0, <1 empty item> ]
```

Comment: i added this because it was not in any of the existing answers, and for node it is the best answer.

it is easy to look up the docs for it in https://github.com/nodejs/node/

Comment: `process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails` is `undefined` on node 16!

Comment: Node 16 code seems to reference a new function, internalBinding, but it doesn't seem to work for me: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v16.13.1/lib/internal/webstreams/util.js#L40-L43=

Comment: You need to pass it a CLI flag. Stop using our internal APIs it makes it super hard to refactor. Instead make the case for why you want us to add a public API and we’ll discuss it and understand each other.

Answer (score 10):

You can use an (ugly) hack in Node.js until a native method is offered:

```
util = require('util');

var promise1 = new Promise (function (resolve) {
}

var promise2 = new Promise (function (resolve) {

    resolve ('foo');
}

state1 = util.inspect (promise1);
state2 = util.inspect (promise2);

if (state1 === 'Promise { <pending> }') {

    console.log('pending'); // pending
}

if (state2 === "Promise { 'foo' }") {

    console.log ('foo') // foo
}
```

Comment: I've boiled it down to a polyfill: `Promise.prototype.isPending = function(){ return util.inspect(this).indexOf("<pending>")>-1; }`

Comment: That's _horrendous_.

Comment: @JohnWeisz What's horrendous is the lack of backwards compatibility. I'm trying to integrate a promise-ful API to a codebase which assumes everything is synchronous. It's either doing something horrendous or rewriting huge chunks of code. Either way I'm committing an atrocity.

Comment: just use `process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails`

Comment: @Tustin2121 For some version it will fail with something like `Promise.resolve('<pending>')`.

Comment: @amara `process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails` is `undefined` on node 16!

Answer (score 9):

#### Updated: 2019

Bluebird.js offers this: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/isfulfilled.html

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
let p = Promise.resolve();
console.log(p.isFulfilled());
```

If you'd prefer to create your own wrapper, here is a [nice blog](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/317/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-promise-has-been-fulfilled-rejected-or-resolved) about it.

Because JavaScript is single-threaded, it's hard to find a common enough use case to justify putting this in the spec.  The best place to know if a promise is resolved is in .then().  Testing if a Promise is fullfilled would create a polling loop which is most likely the wrong direction.

[async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) is a nice construct if you'd like to reason async code synchronously.

```
await this();
await that();
return 'success!';
```

Another useful call is [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

When I first reached for this answer, that is the use case I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

It's indeed quite annoying that this basic functionality is missing. If you're using node.js then I know of two workarounds, neither of 'em very pretty. Both snippets below implement the same API:

```js
> Promise.getInfo( 42 )                         // not a promise
{ status: 'fulfilled', value: 42 }
> Promise.getInfo( Promise.resolve(42) )        // fulfilled
{ status: 'fulfilled', value: 42 }
> Promise.getInfo( Promise.reject(42) )         // rejected
{ status: 'rejected', value: 42 }
> Promise.getInfo( p = new Promise(() => {}) )  // unresolved
{ status: 'pending' }
> Promise.getInfo( Promise.resolve(p) )         // resolved but pending
{ status: 'pending' }
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to distinguish the last two promise states using either trick.

### 1. Use the V8 debug API

This is the same trick that `util.inspect` uses.

```js
const Debug = require('vm').runInDebugContext('Debug');

Promise.getInfo = function( arg ) {
    let mirror = Debug.MakeMirror( arg, true );
    if( ! mirror.isPromise() )
        return { status: 'fulfilled', value: arg };
    let status = mirror.status();
    if( status === 'pending' )
        return { status };
    if( status === 'resolved' )  // fix terminology fuck-up
        status = 'fulfilled';
    let value = mirror.promiseValue().value();
    return { status, value };
};
```

### 2. Synchronously run microtasks

This avoids the debug API, but has some frightening semantics by causing all pending microtasks and `process.nextTick` callbacks to be run synchronously. It also has the side-effect of preventing the "unhandled promise rejection" error from ever being triggered for the inspected promise.

```js
Promise.getInfo = function( arg ) {
    const pending = {};
    let status, value;
    Promise.race([ arg, pending ]).then(
        x => { status = 'fulfilled'; value = x; },
        x => { status = 'rejected'; value = x; }
    );
    process._tickCallback();  // run microtasks right now
    if( value === pending )
        return { status: 'pending' };
    return { status, value };
};
```

Comment: It is very unsafe to do `process._tickCallback` (or even plain %RunMicrotick) - it will randomly break things in your code. I desperately tried getting it to work (for fake timers in async functions, mostly) and it was never stable enough from the Node side. I sort of gave up working on it. The V8 debug mirror API is entirely appropriate here.

Comment: And.. `DeprecationWarning: DebugContext has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version.` :( Looks like V8 removed it

Comment: We (Node) can totally ask V8 for an API or expose an API for looking at a promise's state directly though - if you open an issue at https://github.com/nodejs/promise-use-cases I will bring it up with V8 happily

Comment: A comment further down in this topic revealed that an API already appears to exist: `process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails( promise )` returns `[ 0, ]` for pending, `[ 1, value ]` for fulfilled, and `[ 2, value ]` for rejected.

Answer (score 8):

`await` usage to [@jib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564053#answer-35820220), with idiomatic prototyping.

```
Object.defineProperty(Promise.prototype, "state", {
    get: function(){
        const o = {};
        return Promise.race([this, o]).then(
            v => v === o ? "pending" : "resolved",
            () => "rejected");
    }
});

// usage: console.log(await <Your Promise>.state);
(async () => {
    console.log(await Promise.resolve(2).state);  // "resolved"
    console.log(await Promise.reject(0).state);   // "rejected"
    console.log(await new Promise(()=>{}).state); // "pending"
})();
```

note that this async function execute "almost" immediately like synced function (or actually possibly be instantly).

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap your promises in this way

```
function wrapPromise(promise) {
  var value, error,
      settled = false,
      resolved = false,
      rejected = false,
      p = promise.then(function(v) {
        value = v;
        settled = true;
        resolved = true;
        return v;
      }, function(err) {
        error = err;
        settled = true;
        rejected = true;
        throw err;
      });
      p.isSettled = function() {
        return settled;
      };
      p.isResolved = function() {
        return resolved;
      };
      p.isRejected = function() {
        return rejected;
      };
      p.value = function() {
        return value;
      };
      p.error = function() {
        return error;
      };
      var pThen = p.then, pCatch = p.catch;
      p.then = function(res, rej) {
        return wrapPromise(pThen(res, rej));
      };
      p.catch = function(rej) {
        return wrapPromise(pCatch(rej));
      };
      return p;
}
```

Comment: This would require OP to get access to the promise _in a previous turn of the event loop_. Since `.then` always executes asynchronously OP who wants to inspect a promise _in the same turn_ will not get the correct result here. Note OP asked specifically about _synchronous_ inspection and mentioned that they already know about asynchronous inspection.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: wouldn't the default values come up if code on the same "turn" called it?

Comment: Of course you'd have to wrap all your promises at creation time. e.g. inside the functions that create and return them.

Comment: Right, at which point they're not really native promises anymore, you might as well extend them the way they're meant to be extended with subclassing which would allow you to do this elegantly instead of monkey patching properties on an object.

Comment: Whether you extend a promise the way I showed or by sub-classing, in each case you'd still have to add your own version of then and catch.

Comment: Right, at which point you're no longer using native promises but your own versions of the functions that make a promise a promise - so you might as well use a library or subclass.

Comment: Then maybe you could show us your elegant solution. Because I don't think doing this by sub-classing (i.e. using a prototype chain) is going to be more elegant.

Comment: This is actually a pretty workable solution for me. However, I will be marking the other response as "the answer", as these stop being "pure JavaScript Promises" once you duck-punch them like this.

Answer (score 6):

I looked through the solutions proposed to this question and could not see one that corresponds to a simple approach that I have used in Node.js.

I have defined a simple class PromiseMonitor, which takes a promise as the single parameter to its constructor, and has a string property `.status` which returns the standard string values corresponding to the promise status, "pending", "resolved" or "rejected", and four boolean properties `.pending`, `.resolved`, `.rejected` and `.error`. The property `.error` is set true only if `.rejected` is true **and** the reject callback was passed an Error object.

The class simply uses `.then()` on the promise to change the status of the PromiseMonitor when the promise is resolved or rejected. It does not interfere with any other use of the original promise. Here is the code:

```
class PromiseMonitor {
    constructor(prm){
        this._status = "pending";
        this._pending = true;
        this._resolved = false;
        this._rejected = false;
        this._error = false;
        prm
            .then( ()=>{  
                        this._status = "resolved"; 
                        this._resolved = true; 
                        this._pending = false; 
                    } 
                , (err)=>{ 
                        this._status = "rejected";
                        this._pending = false;
                        this._rejected = true;
                        this._error = err instanceof Error ? true: false ; 
                    } 
                );
    }

    get status(){ return this._status; };
    get pending(){ return this._pending; };
    get resolved(){ return this._resolved; };
    get rejected(){ return this._rejected; };
    get error(){ return this._error };
};
```

To monitor the status of a Promise, simply create an instance of PromiseMonitor, passing the promise in as a parameter, for example:

```
let promiseObject = functionThatReturnsAPromise();
let promiseMonitor = new PromiseMonitor( promiseObject );
```

Now you can syncrhonously check all the properties of promiseMonitor, which will track the status of the original promise. Here is a test script that demonstrates the three possible resolutions of a promise being monitored.

```
let ticks = 0;
let tickerID = setInterval( ()=>{++ticks; console.log(`..tick ${ticks}`)}, 1000);

async function run(){
    console.log("Start");

    let delay = prmDelay(2000);
    let delayMonitor = new PromiseMonitor(delay);

    // normal handling of delay promise
    delay.then((result)=>( console.log("Normal resolution of delay using .then()") ) );

    console.log("delay at start:\n", delay);
    console.log("delayMonitor at start:\n", delayMonitor);
    await delay;
    console.log("delay finished:\n", delay);
    console.log("delayMonitor finished:\n", delayMonitor);


    console.log("\n\n TEST2: Rejection without an Error test ================================")
    let rejDelay = prmDelay(3000, "reject");
    let rejMonitor = new PromiseMonitor(rejDelay);

    // normal handling of reject result on promise
    rejDelay.then((result)=>( console.log("Normal resolution of rejDelay using .then will not happen") ) 
                    , (err)=>( console.log("Rejection of rejDelay handled using .then")));

    console.log("rejDelay at start:\n", rejDelay);
    console.log("rejMonitor at start:\n", rejMonitor);

    await rejDelay.catch( (err)=>{ console.log( "Caught error using .catch on rejDelay" ); });

    console.log("rejDelay finished:\n", rejDelay);
    console.log("rejMonitor finished:\n", rejMonitor);


    console.log("\n\n TEST3: Rejection with an Error test ================================")
    let errMonitor ;
    let errDelay;
    try{

        errDelay = prmDelay(1000, "error");
        errMonitor = new PromiseMonitor(errDelay);
        
        // normal handling of results of the original promise
        errDelay.then(
            (result)=>{ 
                console.log("Normal expiry of errDelay");
                console.log("Monitor Status is " + errMonitor.status )
            } 
            , (err)=>{
                console.log("** Rejection of errDelay handled using .then()");
                console.log("   Monitor Status is " + errMonitor.status )
            }
        );

        console.log("errDelay at start:\n", errDelay);
        console.log("errMonitor at start:\n", errMonitor);

        await errDelay;

        console.log("**** This should never be run");

    } catch(err) { 

        console.log( "** Caught error on errDelay using try{}catch{}:" ); 
        console.log( "   Monitor Status is " + errMonitor.status )

    };

    console.log("errDelay finished:\n", errDelay);
    console.log("errMonitor finished:\n", errMonitor);
    

    clearInterval(tickerID);


}

/**
 * Creates a new promise with a specific result
 * @param {*} tt 
 * @param {*} exitType ("resolve", "reject" or "error")
 */
function prmDelay (tt, exitType) {
    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if( exitType == 'reject' ){
            setTimeout(()=>{ reject("REJECTED")}, tt);
        } else if( exitType== 'error'){
            setTimeout(()=>{ reject(new Error( "ERROR Rejection") ); }, tt);
        } else {
            setTimeout(()=>{ resolve("RESOLVED") }, tt);
        } ;
    });
};


run();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a method to Promise.prototype. It looks like this:

**Edited:** The first solution is not working properly, like most of the answers here. It returns "pending" until the asynchronous function ".then" is invoked, which is not happen immediately. (The same is about solutions using Promise.race). My second solution solves this problem.

```
if (window.Promise) {
    Promise.prototype.getState = function () {
        if (!this.state) {
            this.state = "pending";
            var that = this;
            this.then(
                function (v) {
                    that.state = "resolved";
                    return v;
                },
                function (e) {
                    that.state = "rejected";
                    return e;
                });
        }
        return this.state;
    };
}
```

You can use it on any Promise. For exemple:

```
myPromise = new Promise(myFunction);
console.log(myPromise.getState()); // pending|resolved|rejected
```

**Second (and correct) solution:**

```
if (window.Promise) {
    Promise.stateable = function (func) {
        var state = "pending";
        var pending = true;
        var newPromise = new Promise(wrapper);
        newPromise.state = state;
        return newPromise;
        function wrapper(resolve, reject) {
            func(res, rej);
            function res(e) {
                resolve(e);
                if (pending) {
                    if (newPromise)
                        newPromise.state = "resolved";
                    else
                        state = "resolved";
                    pending = false;
                }
            }
            function rej(e) {
                reject(e);
                if (pending) {
                    if (newPromise)
                        newPromise.state = "rejected";
                    else
                        state = "rejected";
                    pending = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And use it:

**Notice**: In this solution you doesn't have to use the "new" operator.

```
myPromise = Promise.stateable(myFunction);
console.log(myPromise.state); // pending|resolved|rejected
```

Answer (score 3):

what you can do, is to use a variable to store the state, manually set the state to that variable, and check that variable.

```
var state = 'pending';

new Promise(function(ff, rjc) {
  //do something async

  if () {//if success
    state = 'resolved';

    ff();//
  } else {
    state = 'rejected';

    rjc();
  }
});

console.log(state);//check the state somewhere else in the code
```

of course, this means you must have access to the original code of the promise. If you don't, then you can do:

```
var state = 'pending';

//you can't access somePromise's code
somePromise.then(function(){
  state = 'resolved';
}, function() {
  state = 'rejected';
})

console.log(state);//check the promise's state somewhere else in the code
```

My solution is more coding, but I think you probably wouldn't have to do this for every promise you use.

Comment: The simplest answer; I was going to post something like this, I'm glad it was already here.

Comment: Btw: I like to use constructs like this when I'm doing it synchronously: `let result = await somePromise.then(v=>{ok:v}, e=>{failed:e});`, then the status and value/error is left in `result`.

Answer (score 3):

Caveat: This method uses undocumented Node.js internals and could be changed without warning.

In Node you can synchronously determine a promise's state using `process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails(/* promise */);`.

This will return:

`[0, ]` for pending,

`[1, /* value */]` for fulfilled, or

`[2, /* value */]` for rejected.

```
const pending = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('yakko')));;
const fulfilled = Promise.resolve('wakko');
const rejected = Promise.reject('dot');

[pending, fulfilled, rejected].forEach(promise => {
  console.log(process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails(promise));
});

// pending:   [0, ]
// fulfilled: [1, 'wakko']
// rejected:  [2, 'dot']
```

Wrapping this into a helper function:

```
const getStatus = promise => ['pending', 'fulfilled', 'rejected'][
  process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails(promise)[0]
];

getStatus(pending); // pending
getStatus(fulfilled); // fulfilled
getStatus(rejected); // rejected
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work from within `jest` (which is the only place I'm interested in it, really).  The function exists, but always seems to return `undefined`.  How do I find out what's wrong?

Comment: Hmm, I remember it working within `mocha`; never tried it with `jest` though. Maybe start a new question linking here and include your Node.js version as well as `jest` version?

Comment: Not something I'm interested in a great deal any more, unfortunately.  I was basically looking to sanity test my manually-resolvable/rejectable `Promise` that I was only using to test stuff that should be going on while a `Promise` is pending, but I figured so long as what I wrote, works, then there's no need to test that in addition to what relies on it.

Answer (score 3):

There's another **elegant** & hacky way of checking if a promise is still pending just by converting  the whole object to string and check it with the help of inspect like this: `util.inspect(myPromise).includes("pending")`.

Tested on Node.js 8,9,10,11,12,13

Here's a full example

```
const util = require("util")

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async ()=>{
  let letmesleep = sleep(3000)
  setInterval(()=>{
    console.log(util.inspect(letmesleep).includes("pending"))
  },1000)
})()
```

Result:

```
true
true
false
false
false
```

Comment: This is an interesting hack, but keep in mind that `util.inspect` is intended for debugging and it should not be heavily relied upon, since [it's output may change at any time](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options).

Comment: Also, `util.inspect` is not available in the browser (without a polyfill).

Answer (score 2):

As of Node.js version 8, you can now use the [wise-inspection](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/wise-inspection) package to synchronously inspect native promises (without any dangerous hacks).

Answer (score 2):

I made a [package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-state) for this. Unlike most of the other answers here, it doesn't swallow unhandled rejections.

```
npm install p-state
```

```js
import timers from 'timers/promises';
import {promiseStateSync} from 'p-state';

const timeoutPromise = timers.setTimeout(100);

console.log(promiseStateSync(timeoutPromise));
//=> 'pending'

await timeoutPromise;

console.log(promiseStateSync(timeoutPromise));
//=> 'fulfilled'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like somehow nobody came up with one of the simplest solution that doesn't require any hacks:

- define a variable to indicate that the promise is running
- Add a `.finally` clause to the promise that sets the variable to false (you can do it at any time after the promise is created)
- After that in your code just check if the above variable is true or false, to see whether the Promise is still running.

If you want to know not just whether it's finished or not then instead of `.finally` add a `.then` and a `.catch` clauses that set the variable to  "resolved" or "rejected".

The only drawback is that the state variable doesn't get set right away (synchronously) when you add the clauses, in case the promise has already finished. Because of this, it's best to add this to the earliest possible place after the creation of the promise.

Example:

```
async function worker(){
  // wait a very short period of time
  await (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100)))
  //...
}

const w1=worker()


let w1_running=true
w1.finally( ()=> {w1_running=false});

//...
//Then check if it's running

(async ()=>{
  while(true){
    if (w1_running) {
      console.log("Still Busy :(")
    } else {
      console.log("All done :)")
      break
    }
    await (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10)))
  }
})()

// Note we need some async action started otherwise the event loop would never reach the code in the function `worker` or in the `.finally` clause
```

Comment: Re "add a .then and a .catch clause": You can just use a .then for that; the second parameter is a rejection callback and behaves like .catch, e.g.: `.then(v => /* resolved with v */, e => /* rejected with e */)`. I like to use constructs like this when I'm doing it synchronously: `let result = await someArbitraryPromise.then(v => { ok: v }, e => { failed: e });`, then the status is left in `result`.

Comment: By far the most non-performant answer, do not use if you care about a well-styled and performant application

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more fleshed out es6 version of the QueryablePromise, allowing the ability to chain then and catch after the first resolve and to immediately resolve or reject to keep the api consistent with the native Promise.

```js
const PROMISE = Symbol('PROMISE')
const tap = fn => x => (fn(x), x)
const trace = label => tap(x => console.log(label, x))

class QueryablePromise {
  resolved = false
  rejected = false
  fulfilled = false
  catchFns = []
  constructor(fn) {
    this[PROMISE] = new Promise(fn)
      .then(tap(() => {
        this.fulfilled = true
        this.resolved = true
      }))
      .catch(x => {
        this.fulfilled = true
        this.rejected = true
        return Promise.reject(x)
      })
  }
  then(fn) {
    this[PROMISE].then(fn)
    return this
  }
  catch(fn) {
    this[PROMISE].catch(fn)
    return this
  }
  static resolve(x) {
    return new QueryablePromise((res) => res(x))
  }
  static reject(x) {
    return new QueryablePromise((_, rej) => rej(x))
  }
}

const resolvedPromise = new QueryablePromise((res) => {
  setTimeout(res, 200, 'resolvedPromise')
})

const rejectedPromise = new QueryablePromise((_, rej) => {
  setTimeout(rej, 200, 'rejectedPromise')
})

// ensure our promises have not been fulfilled
console.log('test 1 before: is resolved', resolvedPromise.resolved)
console.log('test 2 before: is rejected', rejectedPromise.rejected)


setTimeout(() => {
  // check to see the resolved status of our promise
  console.log('test 1 after: is resolved', resolvedPromise.resolved)
  console.log('test 2 after: is rejected', rejectedPromise.rejected)
}, 300)

// make sure we can immediately resolve a QueryablePromise
const immediatelyResolvedPromise = QueryablePromise.resolve('immediatelyResolvedPromise')
  // ensure we can chain then
  .then(trace('test 3 resolved'))
  .then(trace('test 3 resolved 2'))
  .catch(trace('test 3 rejected'))

// make sure we can immediately reject a QueryablePromise
const immediatelyRejectedPromise = QueryablePromise.reject('immediatelyRejectedPromise')
  .then(trace('test 4 resolved'))
  .catch(trace('test 4 rejected'))
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

2019:

The simple way to do that as I know is `thenable` , super thin wrapper around promise or any async job.

```js
const sleep = (t) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res,t));
const sleeping = sleep(30);

function track(promise){
    let state = 'pending';
    promise = promise.finally( _=> state ='fulfilled');
    return {
        get state(){return state},
        then: promise.then.bind(promise), /*thentable*/
        finally:promise.finally.bind(promise),
        catch:promise.catch.bind(promise),
    }
}


promise = track(sleeping);
console.log(promise.state) // pending

promise.then(function(){
    console.log(promise.state); // fulfilled
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can `extend` the Promise class to create a new **queryable** Promise
>   class.

You can create your own subclass, say `QueryablePromise`, by inheriting from the natively available `Promise` class, the instances of which would have a `status` property available on it that you can use to query the status of the promise objects **synchronously**. An implementation of it can be seen below or refer [this](https://medium.com/@UtkarshPramodGupta/how-to-make-a-stateful-promise-in-javascript-4e08418716ad) for a better explanation.

```js
class QueryablePromise extends Promise {
  constructor (executor) {
    super((resolve, reject) => executor(
      data => {
        resolve(data)
        this._status = 'Resolved'
      },
      err => {
        reject(err)
        this._status = 'Rejected'
      },
    ))
    this._status = 'Pending'
  }

  get status () {
    return this._status
  }
}
 
// Create a promise that resolves after 5 sec 
var myQueryablePromise = new QueryablePromise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 5000)
})

// Log the status of the above promise every 500ms
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(myQueryablePromise.status)
}, 500)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no existing API will return this new class. How are you imagining people use this?

Comment: @jib Thanks for your response. What do you mean that no API would return this class? :(

Comment: No *existing* APIs will return it, because they would have to be written to return it, right? E.g. if I call [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) it will return a native promise. How would your class help with that?

Comment: Well, can't we just wrap that fetch call in our new QuerablePromise like: `const queryableFetch = new QueryablePromise((resolve, reject) => {fetch(/.../).then((data) => resolve(data)) })` ? Or, is there an issue with that? :/

Comment: That should work, just don't forget `, err => reject(err)` as a second arg to `then` or it won't propagate errors correctly (among the reasons it's considered the [promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)). It's not truly synchronous though (e.g. won't detect an already-resolved promise), but perhaps useful in cases where you don't control the caller and the answer is needed immediately.

Comment: Please stop spamming links to this answer below other people's content.

Answer (score 1):

*CAVEAT: `process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails` is `undefined` on node 16!*

## Benchmark:

#### Candidates:

```js
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009572/5318303
 */
const isPromisePending1 = (() => { // noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
    const util = process.binding('util')  // noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
    return promise => !util.getPromiseDetails(promise)[0]
})()

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/35852666/5318303
 */
const isPromisePending2 = (promise) => util.inspect(promise) === 'Promise { <pending> }'

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/35820220/5318303
 */
const isPromisePending3 = (promise) => {
    const t = {}
    return Promise.race([promise, t])
            .then(v => v === t, () => false)
}
```

#### Test promises:

```js
const a = Promise.resolve()
const b = Promise.reject()
const c = new Promise(() => {})
const x = (async () => 1)()
```

#### Run benchmark:

```js
const n = 1000000

console.time('isPromisePending1')
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    isPromisePending1(a)
    isPromisePending1(b)
    isPromisePending1(c)
    isPromisePending1(x)
}
console.timeEnd('isPromisePending1')

console.time('isPromisePending2')
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    isPromisePending2(a)
    isPromisePending2(b)
    isPromisePending2(c)
    isPromisePending2(x)
}
console.timeEnd('isPromisePending2')

console.time('isPromisePending3')
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    await isPromisePending3(a)
    await isPromisePending3(b)
    await isPromisePending3(c)
    await isPromisePending3(x)
}
console.timeEnd('isPromisePending3')
```

### Result:

```
isPromisePending1: 440.694ms
isPromisePending2: 3.354s
isPromisePending3: 4.761s
```

**Obviously `isPromisePending1()` is too faster (8~10 times)! But it's not usable on node 16! (see above caveat).**

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of rather complex answers here -- likely because this question was asked before we had better support for [ES6 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and [Private Fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields). Now that modern browsers support these features, I have a **simple, modern, native/package-free solution** below. (Note that, as [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30564128/17777687) said, a solution is not possible with the `Promise` class *alone*; so we need to extend the class to get what we want.)

```js
class WatchablePromise extends Promise {
  #settled = false;
  #status = "pending";

  constructor(executor) {
    super((resolve, reject) => {
      executor(
        (value) => {
          resolve(value);
          this.#settled = true;
          this.#status = "fulfilled";
        },
        (reason) => {
          reject(reason);
          this.#settled = true;
          this.#status = "rejected";
        },
      );
    });
  }

  get settled() {
    return this.#settled;
  }

  get status() {
    return this.#status;
  }
}

async function testCustomPromise() {
  const promise = new WatchablePromise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  promise.then(() => console.log("Settled: ", promise.settled)); // Settled: true

  await promise;
  console.log("Status: ", promise.status); // Status: fulfilled
}

testCustomPromise();
```

Obviously, you can customize this further according to your needs. The one caveat is that you'll need to use this custom class instead of using the regular `Promise` class whenever you want to spy on the details of the promise. But hopefully the number of times you'll need to do this will be minimal. I only came up with this solution because I'm trying to test a library that I'm working on.

---

For TS users, it's important to note that TypeScript's definition of a `Promise` is rather complex because it defines both an interface type *and* a constructor type. So I had to reuse what they define on `PromiseConstructor` and come up with something like this:

```
class WatchablePromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
  #settled = false;
  #status: "pending" | "fulfilled" | "rejected" = "pending";

  constructor(
    executor: (resolve: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: unknown) => void) => void
  ) {
    super((resolve, reject) => {
      executor(
        (value) => {
          resolve(value);
          this.#settled = true;
          this.#status = "fulfilled";
        },
        (reason) => {
          reject(reason);
          this.#settled = true;
          this.#status = "rejected";
        }
      );
    });
  }

  get settled() {
    return this.#settled;
  }

  get status() {
    return this.#status;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ES7 experimental you can use async to easily wrap the promise you want to listen.

```
async function getClient() {
  let client, resolved = false;
  try {
    client = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let client = new Client();

      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
         reject(new Error(`timeout`, 1000));
         client.close();
      });

      client.on('ready', () => {
        if(!resolved) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
          resolve(client);
        }
      });

      client.on('error', (error) => {
        if(!resolved) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
          reject(error);
        }
      });

      client.on('close', (hadError) => {
        if(!resolved && !hadError) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
          reject(new Error("close"));
        }
      });
    });

    resolved = true;
  } catch(error) {
    resolved = true;
    throw error;
  }
  return client;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a little npm package, promise-value, which provides a promise wrapper with a `resolved` flag:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-value

It also gives synchronous access to the promise value (or error). This doesn't alter the Promise object itself, following the wrap rather than extend pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is older question but I was trying to do something similar.  I need to keep n workers going.  They are structured in a promise.  I need to scan and see if they are resolved, rejected or still pending.  If resolved, I need the value, if rejected do something to correct the issue or pending.  If resolved or rejected I need to start another task to keep n going.  I can't figure a way to do it with Promise.all or Promise.race as I keep working promises in an array and can find no way to delete them.  So I create a worker that does the trick

I need a promise generator function that returns a promise which resolves or rejects as necessary.  It is called by a function that sets up the framework to know what the promise is doing.

In the code below the generator simply returns a promise based on setTimeout.

Here it is

```
//argObj should be of form
// {succeed: <true or false, nTimer: <desired time out>}
function promiseGenerator(argsObj) {
  let succeed = argsObj.succeed;          
  let nTimer = argsObj.nTimer;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (succeed) {
        resolve('ok');
      }
      else {
        reject(`fail`);
      }
    }, nTimer);
  })

}

function doWork(generatorargs) {
  let sp = { state: `pending`, value: ``, promise: "" };
  let p1 = promiseGenerator(generatorargs)
    .then((value) => {
      sp.state = "resolved";
      sp.value = value;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      sp.state = "rejected";
      sp.value = err;
    })
  sp.promise = p1;
  return sp;
}
```

doWork returns an object containing the promise and the its state and returned value.

The following code runs a loop that tests the state and creates new workers to keep it at 3 running workers.

```
let promiseArray = [];

promiseArray.push(doWork({ succeed: true, nTimer: 1000 }));
promiseArray.push(doWork({ succeed: true, nTimer: 500 }));
promiseArray.push(doWork({ succeed: false, nTimer: 3000 }));

function loopTimerPromise(delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('ok');
    }, delay)
  })
}

async function looper() {
  let nPromises = 3;      //just for breaking loop
  let nloop = 0;          //just for breaking loop
  let i;
  //let continueLoop = true;
  while (true) {
    await loopTimerPromise(900);  //execute loop every 900ms
    nloop++;
    //console.log(`promiseArray.length = ${promiseArray.length}`);
    for (i = promiseArray.length; i--; i > -1) {
      console.log(`index ${i} state: ${promiseArray[i].state}`);
      switch (promiseArray[i].state) {
        case "pending":
          break;
        case "resolved":
          nPromises++;
          promiseArray.splice(i, 1);
          promiseArray.push(doWork({ succeed: true, nTimer: 1000 }));
          break;
        case "rejected":
          //take recovery action
          nPromises++;
          promiseArray.splice(i, 1);
          promiseArray.push(doWork({ succeed: false, nTimer: 500 }));
          break;
        default:
          console.log(`error bad state in i=${i} state:${promiseArray[i].state} `)
          break;
      }
    }
    console.log(``);
    if (nloop > 10 || nPromises > 10) {
      //should do a Promise.all on remaining promises to clean them up but not for test
      break;
    }
  }
}

looper();
```

Tested in node.js

BTW Not in this answer so much but in others on similar topics, I HATE it when someone says "you don't understand" or "that's not how it works"  I generally assume the questioner knows what they want.  Suggesting a better way is great.  A patient explanation of how promises work would also be good.

Answer (score 0):

Old question with many answers but none seem to suggest what I think is the simplest solution: set a bool indicator on promise resolution/rejection.

```js
class Promise2 {
  constructor(...args) {
    let promise = new Promise(...args);
    promise.then(() => promise._resolved_ = true);
    promise.catch(() => promise._rejected_ = true);
    return promise;
  }
}

let p = new Promise2(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));

setInterval(() => {
  console.log('checking synchronously if p is resolved yet?', p._resolved_);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: That's not a valid answer because it implies you have access to the implementation of the Promise callback, which is likely not the case otherwise, yes, it would be as simple as setting a flag.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `Future` pattern I use: (https://github.com/Smallscript-Corp)

- enables `sync` and `async` fn usage
- enables **event** patterns to be unified with `async` behavior

```
class XPromise extends Promise {
  state = 'pending'
  get settled() {return(this.state !== 'pending')}
  resolve(v,...a) {
    this.state = 'resolved'
    return(this.resolve_(this.value = v,...a))
  }
  reject(e,...a) {
    this.state = 'rejected'
    return(this.reject_(this.value = (e instanceof Error) ? e : XPromise.Error(e),...a))
  }
  static Error(e) {const v = Error('value-rejected'); v.value = e; return(v)}
  static Future(fn,...args) { // FactoryFn
    let r,t,fv = new XPromise((r_,t_) => {r=r_;t=t_})
    fv.resolve_ = r; fv.reject_  = t;
    switch(typeof fn) {
      case 'undefined': break; case 'function': fn(fv,...args); break;
      default: fv.resolve(fn)
    }
    return(fv)
  }
}
global.Future = XPromise.Future
```

Then you can create *future-value* instances that can be resolved using sync and async functions; enables handling events uniformly.

You can use it to write a pattern like:

```
async doSomething() {
  // Start both - logically async-parallel
  const fvIsNetworkOnLine = this.fvIsNetworkOnline
  const fvAuthToken = this.fvAuthToken
  // await both (order not critical since both started/queued above)
  await fvAuthToken
  await fvIsNetworkOnLine
  // ... we can check the future values here if needed `fv.resolved`, `fv.state` etc
  // ... do dependent workflow here ...
}
onNetworkOnLine(fIsOnline) {
  // We utilize the `fv.settled` below, and use the event to `settle` it etc
  if(fIsOnline) {
    if(this.fvNetworkAvailable_)
      this.fvNetworkAvailable_.resolve(true)
    this.fvNetworkAvailable_ = undefined
  }
  else if(this.fvNetworkAvailable_.settled) {
    this.fvNetworkAvailable_ = undefined
  }
}
get fvNetworkAvailable() {
  if(navigator.onLine)
    return true
  else if(this.fvNetworkAvailable_)
    return this.fvNetworkAvailable_
  return (this.fvNetworkAvailable_ = Future())
}
get fvAuthToken() {
  if(this.fvAuthToken_)
    return this.fvAuthToken_
  const authTokenFv = async fv => {
    // ... handle retry logic etc here ...
  }
  return(this.fvAuthToken_ = Future(authTokenFv))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own observable promises (`OP` class) then this functionality is rather simple. Plus you can even prematuraly resolve or reject it externally  because I expose the `resolve` and `reject` functions as well. This means you can abort a promise whenever you want by calling it's `.reject(e)` method. Obviously this is not inline with the Promise specificiations A+. Yet, while we don't extend the `Promise` class, as a draft it should still be compatible with the native promises and `async-await`. Since this eliminates the well thought precautions of async operations, you should be careful when using abstractions like this one.

I have also added some extra functionalities like `wait` and `log` to show how easy it would be to chain up custom async tasks in a sane manner.

```js
class OP {
  #p;
  #r;
  #s;
  #v;
  #x;
  static resolve = r => new OP(v => v(r));
  static reject  = e => new OP((_,x) => x(e));
  constructor(cb) {
    this.#p = new Promise((v,x) => ( this.#v = v
                                   , this.#x = x
                                   , cb && cb( r => this.resolve(r)
                                             , e => this.reject(e)
                                             )
                                   ));
    this.#s = "pending";
    this.#r;
  }
  
  get status(){
    return this.#s;
  }

  get result(){
    return this.#r;
  }

  resolve(r){
    this.#v(r);
    this.#s === "pending" && ( this.#s = "resolved"
                             , this.#r = r
                             );
  }

  reject(e){
    this.#x(e);
    this.#s === "pending" && ( this.#s = "rejected"
                             , this.#r = e
                             );   
  }
  
  then(onFulfilled,onRejected){
    return new OP((v,x) => this.#p.then( r => v(onFulfilled ? onFulfilled(r) : r)
                                        , e => v(onRejected ? onRejected(e) : e)
                                        ));
  }
  catch(onRejected){
    return new OP((v,x) => this.#p.catch(e => v(onRejected ? onRejected(e) : e)));
  }
  finally(onFinally){
    return new OP((v,x) => this.#p.finally(_ => v(onFinally ? onFinally() : void 0)));
  }
  
  wait(ms){
      return this.then(r => new OP((v,x) => setTimeout(v,ms,r)))
  }
  log(str){
      return this.then(r => (console.log(str ? str : r),r));
  }
}


var p = new OP((v,x) => setTimeout(v,1000,"OP works..!")),
    q = new OP((v,x) => setTimeout(v,2000,"OP works also with Promise methods..!"));
setTimeout(_ => console.log(p.status),500);
setTimeout(_ => console.log(p.status),1500);
p.then(str => console.log(str))
 .catch(err => console.log(err));

Promise.all([p,q]).then(rs => rs.forEach(r => console.log(r)));

p.then(str => (console.log(str),str)).then(str => console.log("once again",str));

async function tester(){
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) return await OP.reject("oops the async function threw..!");
  return await new OP((v,x) => setTimeout(v,3000,"OP works with await..!"));
}

tester().then(s => console.log(s)).catch(e => console.log(e));
OP.resolve()
  .wait(4000)
  .log("Hello")
  .wait(1000)
  .log("there")
  .wait(1000)
  .log("something useful..!");
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution to be simple and allow me to continue using native promises but add useful synchronous checks. I also didn't have to pull in an entire promise library.

CAVEAT: This only works if there is some sort of break in the current execution thread to allow the promises to execute BEFORE checking the synchronous constructs. That makes this of more limited usefulness than I'd initially thought -- still useful for my use case though (Thanks [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum) for pointing this out)

```
/**
 * This function allow you to modify a JS Promise by adding some status properties.
 * Based on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485545/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-an-es6-promise-is-fulfilled-rejected-resolved
 * But modified according to the specs of promises : https://promisesaplus.com/
 */
function MakeQuerablePromise(promise) {
    // Don't modify any promise that has been already modified.
    if (promise.isFulfilled) return promise;

    // Set initial state
    var isPending = true;
    var isRejected = false;
    var isFulfilled = false;

    // Observe the promise, saving the fulfillment in a closure scope.
    var result = promise.then(
        function(v) {
            isFulfilled = true;
            isPending = false;
            return v; 
        }, 
        function(e) {
            isRejected = true;
            isPending = false;
            throw e; 
        }
    );

    result.isFulfilled = function() { return isFulfilled; };
    result.isPending = function() { return isPending; };
    result.isRejected = function() { return isRejected; };
    return result;
}

wrappedPromise = MakeQueryablePromise(Promise.resolve(3)); 
setTimeout(function() {console.log(wrappedPromise.isFulfilled())}, 1);
```

From https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/317/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-promise-has-been-fulfilled-rejected-or-resolved which based their answer on [Is there a way to tell if an ES6 promise is fulfilled/rejected/resolved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485545/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-an-es6-promise-is-fulfilled-rejected-resolved)

Comment: As added in your comment on my answer - this is entirely incorrect: that does't let you synchronously inspect the state of a promise  - For example `MakeQueryablePromise(Promise.resolve(3)).isResolved` is false but the promise is quite obviously resolved. Not to mention that answer is also using the term "resolved" and "fulfilled" incorrectly. To do that that answer does you could just add a `.then` handler yourself - which completely misses the point of synchronous inspection.

Comment: I see what you're saying and you make a good point. The single threaded nature of JS is getting in the way isn't it? You have to put a break in the current execution for the promise to be marked as resolved.
`let wrappedPromise = MakeQueryablePromise(Promise.resolve(3));
setTimeout(function() {console.log(wrappedPromise.isFulfilled())}, 1);`
Which as long as you do that, this works nicely. But you have to understand that fact for this to be useful. I'll update the description with that caveat.

I also agree that the function naming could be better/more idiomatic.

Comment: But at that point you could just `then` the original promise and accomplish the same thing since it's asynchronous anyway. There is a way with `process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails` that does seem to work but it's using a private API

Comment: It's obnoxious to have to then all the time and makes the code much more difficult to understand. Especially when all I care about is if the promise has been rejected or not -- so my options are to either store that state somewhere else or do something like this. I admit I didn't read the other solutions here thoroughly before posting my own -- apologies for that. This problem is stickier than I'd at first thought.

Answer (score -1):

```
type PromiseState =
  | 'pending'
  | 'fulfilled'
  | 'rejected';

export async function getPromiseState<T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<PromiseState> {
  return await Promise.race([
    promise.then(() => 'fulfilled', () => 'rejected'),
    new Promise<PromiseState>(() => 'pending'),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: This is `async`, so it does not meet the criteria in the question:

> This question is specifically about synchronous interrogation of a Promise's state.