# How to check if a Promise is pending

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have this situation in which I would like to know what the status is of a promise. Below, the function `start` only calls `someTest` if it is not running anymore (Promise is not pending). The `start` function can be called many times, but if its called while the tests are still running, its not going to wait and returns just `false`

```
class RunTest {
    start() {
         retVal = false;

         if (!this.promise) {
             this.promise = this.someTest();
             retVal = true;                
         }

         if ( /* if promise is resolved/rejected or not pending */ ) {
             this.promise = this.someTest();
             retVal = true;
         }

         return retVal;
    }

    someTest() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // some tests go inhere
        });
    }
}
```

I cannot find a way to simply check the status of a promise. Something like `this.promise.isPending` would be nice :) Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the use case? I don't think native promises support this, it is a weird thing to want to do, but Blubird does http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ispending.html

Comment: Not sure if you've checked Mozilla yet, but they have nice examples and documentation on promises - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: In my case its a `setInterval` calling something async all the time. And that something should only be running one at the time. I could of course set an variable on `this`, like `this.isBusy = true` for example. But in my opinion, that sounds like a work-around for not knowing the status of a promise

Comment: The mozilla page is indeed great, but there is nothing about how to check the status of a promise. If I missed it, please let met know!

Comment: You could use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35820220/918910) since you're using `setInterval` anyway.

Comment: Checking whether a promise is pending doesn't seem "weird", it seems absolutely fundamental.

Comment: I wonder if the people marking this as a duplicate realize, this is a pure javascript question and the duplicate is a node.js question.  One of the votes to mark it as duplicate even mention a node library which does not apply in this case.  Pity.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can attach a `then` handler that sets a `done` flag on the promise (or the `RunTest` instance if you prefer), and test that:

```
     if (!this.promise) {
         this.promise = this.someTest();
         this.promise.finally(() => { this.promise.done = true; });
         retVal = true;                
     }

     if ( this.promise.done ) {
         this.promise = this.someTest();
         this.promise.finally(() => { this.promise.done = true; });
         retVal = true;
     }
```

The `finally()` handler ensures that the `done` flag is set regardless of the outcome of the promise.

You probably want to wrap that in a function though to keep the code DRY.

Comment: I'd guess it would be easier to just do `this.promise = null`

Comment: An "empty" `catch` argument doesn't work. You still need to explicitly pass an empty function, or it is just meaningless.

Comment: @Bergi - good point about the empty catch, correcting now... Regarding `this.promise = null`, it's OK for this specific case, but not as robust in general. For example, of the promise is exposed out of the function, having the property available on the promise is nicer.

Comment: Sure, but usually nobody expects to use such a property on a promise, so there's no need to expose it. In all cases where you think you'd need to determine the state of the promise, what you actually need is checking whether your callback was already called or not.

Comment: FWIW, replacing `.catch(() => {}).then()` with [`.finally()`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=promise-finally) might be considered instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
class RunTest {
   constructor() {
    this.isRunning = false;
   }
   start() {
      console.log('isrunning', this.isRunning);
      var retVal = false;
      if(!this.isRunning) {
        this.promise = this.someTest();
        this.promise.catch().then(() => { this.isRunning = false; });
        retVal = true;                
      }
      return retVal;
    }
    someTest() {
        this.isRunning = true;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(function() {
             //some tests go inhere
             resolve();
           }, 1000);
        });
    }
};

var x = new RunTest();

x.start(); //logs false
x.start(); //logs true

setTimeout(function() {
    //wait for a bit
  x.start(); //logs false
}, 2000);
```

Comment: There's a downside to returning the promise after the `then ()` - you can't have a resolved value passed on to the next handler. Also, this won't work if the tests throw (see my answer about this).

Comment: The `then` callback [has lost the methods context](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tchalvakspam/wszyqj3t/3/

Comment: @Amit Changing to `.then(resp => { this.isRunning = false; return resp; })` resolves this issue easily enough; however, replacing `.catch().then()` with `.finally()` is a much better solution