# Svelte: How to display something only when a promise is not pending?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

In [Svelte's tutorial on await blocks and promises](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks), they show how to display a certain text when a promise is awaiting/resolved/rejected.

But how can you show an element when something is *not* loading? I.e. when the promise has either been resolved or rejected (without duplicating the button in both {:then} and {:catch}, of course)

What I'm looking to do is the following:

```html
{#await promise}
{:then number}
    <MyElement />
{:catch error}
    <MyElement />
{/await}
```

But without duplicating `<MyElement />`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Promises API ([and this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294109/how-to-check-if-a-promise-is-pending), there is no off-the-shelf way to know if a promise has resolved)

You can create a flag that updates when the promise is resolved like

```
// in <script>
let resolved;
promise.then(x => resolved = true).catch(x => resolved = true);
```

and in the end, do

```
{#if resolved}
 <MyElement />
{/if}
```