# How to know if a JavaScript async function is running

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

Say that you have a function `f` that does some asynchronous operations by calling a long-running function `g` and waits for its result before doing more work.

Back in the day when we didn't have async/await, and were forced to use callbacks, I used to do something like this to know if `f` had finished running. By this, I mean that `f` **and all the asynchronous things it was doing** had completed:

```
let running = false;
function f() {
    running = true;
    g(function() {
        running = false;
    });
};
```

Now we have ES6, and I can still do something similar using async/await:

```
let running = false;
async function f() {
    running = true;
    await g();
    running = false;
};
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing the same thing, without having to write a wrapper or aynthing like that, because obviously the JavaScript engine must know whether `f` is finished running or not (i.e. it must know if it's paused its executinon with the `await` keyword, and can be resumed).

Is there any way for my code to know this too?

I know there are modules and libraries that let you do that, and yes I could write a wrapper function, but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: Just use the Promise API? `g().then(() => markFinished())`

Comment: JS is not actually pausing the execution with the `await` word. It is just a syntactic sugar, it creates a callback to your function basically. Just so you know. Sadly, your code is fine, it is your responsibility to know the state of your function.

Comment: You can check this question, it is similar to what you asked

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002028/javascript-how-to-check-if-async-operation-is-still-pending-in-progress