# How would you display a promise object's state and value when overriding console.log

Tags: javascript, html, promise, overriding, console.log

I'm attempting to display the `console.log` output in a div. I'm doing this by overriding the `console.log` function

When I use the original `console.log`, a promise displays, in the console as (see 1. in code below):

```
Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: undefined }
```

When I over-ride it I get, in the div:  :

```
 [object Promise]
```

(see 2. in code below)

How would you adjust the following code to have the `<state>` property displayed in the "main" div?

```js
const pause =  sec => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000 * sec))

// 1. Original console.log
;(async function(){
  await new Promise(resolve => document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', resolve));
  let x = pause(0.5)
  console.log(x)
  await x;
  console.log(x)
})();

// 2. Overridden console.log
;(async function(){
  await new Promise(resolve => document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', resolve));
  await pause(1)
  let divconsole = document.getElementById('main');
  // Override console.log:
  console.log = function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      if (typeof arguments[i] === 'object') {
          divconsole.innerHTML += 'console.log arg ' + String(i) + ':  ' + String(arguments[i]) + '<br>';
      }
    }
  }

  let y = pause(0.5)
  console.log(y)
  await y;
  console.log(y)
})();
```

```html
<div id="main" style="width:100%;height:auto;background-color:lightblue;">

</div>
```

*A note on why I'm asking: I have code with a promise that resolves in a desktop browser and not in a mobile browser. I'm attempt to debug this (without consistent mobile-desktop OS ecosystem). I might write a follow up question if I can replicate it in a simple example.*

Comment: There is no regular Javascript access to the internal state of a promise. `console.log()` has its own access that I don't know of any way to replicate in your own Javascript code.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood; you're trying to access internal promise state.

Comment: Is it possible to make the custom `console.log` asynchronous?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes, but I can't see how it would help (I've checked - it does not affect output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this trick from [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35820220/9867451) to handle the arguments that are of type `Promise` like so. The trick requires the custom `console.log` to be asynchronous like so:

```
function promiseState(p) {
    const t = {};
    return Promise.race([p, t])
      .then(v =>
        (v === t) ? { state: "pending" } : { state: "fulfilled", value: v },
        () => { state: "rejected" }
      );
}

console.log = async function(...args) {
  for (let arg of args) {
    if (arg instanceof Promise) {
      let state = await promiseState(arg);
      divconsole.innerHTML += `Promise { &lt;state&gt;: "${ state.state }"${ state.state === "fulfilled" ? ', &lt;value&gt;: ' + state.value : '' } }<br>`;
    } else if (typeof arg === 'object') {
      divconsole.innerHTML += 'console.log arg:  ' + String(arg) + '<br>';
    }
    // add more else-ifs to handle strings, numbers, booleans, ... etc
  }
}
```

The custom `console.log` needs to be `asynchronous` because it wraps the promise in another promise. This is the only way you can do it.

**Explanation:**

The trick is to `race` the promise `p` against a resolved one (that yields an object `{}`), if the promise `p` is already fulfilled its value will be used and since its value can't be the same as that of the other promise (the one we are racing against, the one that yields `{}`), we determine that the promise has fulfilled. If the value we get is that of the other promise (the object `{}`) meaning that our resolved promise won the race, we can be sure that the promise `p` has not yet fulfilled.

If we get an error (meaning the `catch` callback gets called), the the promise `p` is rejected.

**Demo:**

```js
function promiseState(p) {
  const t = {};
  return Promise.race([p, t])
    .then(v =>
      (v === t) ? { state: "pending" } : { state: "fulfilled", value: v },
      () => { state: "rejected" }
    );
}

console.log = async function(...args) {
  let divconsole = document.getElementById('main');
  
  for (let arg of args) {
    if (arg instanceof Promise) {
      let state = await promiseState(arg);
      divconsole.innerHTML += `Promise { &lt;state&gt;: "${ state.state }"${ state.state === "fulfilled" ? ', &lt;value&gt;: ' + state.value : '' } }<br>`;
    } else if (typeof arg === 'object') {
      divconsole.innerHTML += 'console.log arg:  ' + String(arg) + '<br>';
    }
  }
}

const pause =  sec => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000 * sec));

;(async function() {
  await new Promise(resolve => document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', resolve));
  await pause(1);
  let divconsole = document.getElementById('main');

  let y = pause(0.5);
  await console.log(y);
  await y;
  await console.log(y);
})();
```

```html
<div id="main" style="width:100%;height:auto;background-color:lightblue;"></div>
```

Comment: @atomh33ls Thanks! I've added a short explanation of what the trick does. I hope it's clear

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to cast anything promise-like to it's real value might be:

```js
async function myLog(val) {
  console.log(await val);
}
```

`await` ensures that promises are resolved, but also passes through non-promises just fine.