# Recursive sync function with "isResolved" termination condition

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, promise

Currently, I have defined two functions as follows:

```
function getLock() {
  let promise, isPending;
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    isPending = true;
  } else {
    promise = Promise.resolve();
    isPending = false;
  }
  return [promise, isPending];
};

function waitForLock() {
  const lockAndIsPending = getLock();
  const lock = lockAndIsPending[0];
  const isPending = lockAndIsPending[1];

  if (!isPending) {
    return lock;
  } else {
    return lock.then(waitForLock);
  }
}

waitForLock().then(() => console.log("done"));
```

This is of course for demonstration only. As a necessity of the real world application, `getLock` always needs to return a Promise. **Also, after the lock has been released once, it has to be checked if it is still released (`lock.then(waitForLock)`) because the real release conditions (here modeled by `Math.random()`) could have changed meanwhile due to the asynchrony**. This introduces recursion.

My current code works fine: `waitForLock()` will eventually return because it will happen sometime that `getLock` returns `isPending=false`, fulfilling the termination condition.

But my goal is to get rid of `isPending` as extra return variable. In the future, `getLock` should return a promise only. Unfortunately, it is not possible to check whether a given promise is already resolved or not (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564053/how-can-i-synchronously-determine-a-javascript-promises-state)), so I cannot "calculate" `isPending` in `waitForLock`. So how could I change `waitForLock` accordingly?

**Edit**

The goal is to be able to use any `Promise`-returning function for `getLock` without special constraints on return or resolve values. So, if possible, the logic should all be in `waitForLock`, not in `getLock`.

Comment: Why don't you just `await getLock()` ?

Comment: This wouldn't change the recursion problem, would it? I still would have to decide whether to call `waitForLock` a second time or not.

Comment: I don't think so, see my answer below

Comment: Isn't `waitForLock` already the function you are looking for, which returns a promise for when the lock is released?

Comment: Yes, the current implementation works, but it relies on "additional information" (namely the `isPending` variable) which I want to get rid of.

Comment: It would help if you could post the code of (or at least describe) your real world use case, not just a random variable. In particular, it is unclear how the condition is affected by other code, and how a lock is obtained/released (which needs to be done atomically but your `getLock` code doesn't do anything to that effect).

Comment: @Remirror If the current code works, you can just inline the `getLock` function in the `waitForLock` function, and you have one single function that does what you want and has only a single `if` statement and no boolean variable.

Comment: @Bergi Ok I will think of how to make the scenario more clear. It has something to due with concurrent processes, but it's really difficult to present it in a concise way. Regarding  `getLock`, the idea of separation is to be able to use many different functions in place of `getLock`, not just this one.

Comment: @Remirror Then abstract out the `testLock` part, not the timeout for retrying.

Comment: "*the logic should all be in `waitForLock`, not in `getLock`.*" - but what logic? There's only the retry part, is it not? You require a base case for that recursion, and the only viable approach is a boolean (or null-vs-nonnull etc) result value of the promise, like in @Montecamo's answer. But tbh, I think that's not enough logic to require a separate function at all, you can achieve the same result by just adding `.then(getLock)` to the timeout promise in `getLock` itself.

Comment: It would really help if you could post the complete actual code of what you are doing with concurrent processes here. Or at least the code that regards the lock. It looks (from the name) like you're trying to implement a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
function getLock() {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }

  return Promise.resolve('pending');
};

function waitForLock() {
  const lock = getLock();

  return lock.then((result) => {
    if (result === 'pending') {
      return waitForLock();
    }

    return result;
  })
}

waitForLock().then(() => console.log("done"));
```

Comment: Basically two solutions, as always : "Promise style" with `.then()` callbacks, or "await style".

Comment: @JeremyThille exactly ;)

Comment: Ok thanks, something like that would probably work, but it is kind of cheating because `getLock` still needs to return the `isPending` state (although in another way). The goal is to use _any_ promise-returning function for `getLock`, without special considerations. Sorry for having not made this clear enough, I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you need only one function, that returns a Promise either way, and then just await it :

```js
function getLock() {
  let promise;

  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    console.log("Waiting to unlock...")
    promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve("Unlocked!"), 1000));
  } else {
    console.log("Unlocking immediately.")
    promise = Promise.resolve("Unlocked!");
  }
  return promise;
};

// Testing the above function
(async() => {
  for (let i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) {
    console.log(await getLock())
  }
  console.log("All done")
})()
```

You can even await all of them in parallel :

```js
function getLock() {
  let promise;

  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    console.log("Waiting to unlock...")
    promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve("Unlocked!"), 1000));
  } else {
    console.log("Unlocking immediately.")
    promise = Promise.resolve("Unlocked!");
  }
  return promise;
};

// Testing the above function
(async() => {
  await Promise.all([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map(getLock))
  console.log("All done")
})()
```

Comment: The problem is that after the lock has been unlocked once, it could be relocked again due to new locking conditions that have arisen during the wait, so  in the "waiting" case, I have to recheck it. I admit that this is unfortunately hard to see with my toy example here, but it is not easy to present otherwise.

Comment: Ha, it's getting more complex. I guess you need a Lock class, with a `this.locked` state, and every time this state is changed by something, an unlocking process starts automatically (`this.startUnlocking()`), which eventually will end up with `this.locked=false;`

Comment: Nice idea, I really have to think about the approach again. Thanks so far.