# How to get the promise state when creating a new Auth user in firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am able to create a new user in firebase Authentication like this:

```
const status = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);   
console.log(status);
```

The console shows the output as this:

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]: FirebaseError: Firebase: The email address is badly formatted.
```

How would I get the `PromiseState` from my `status` variable?

Comment: You must read how to use [`async/await` or `Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512388/understanding-async-await-on-nodejs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I synchronously determine a JavaScript Promise's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564053/how-can-i-synchronously-determine-a-javascript-promises-state)

Answer (score 2):

The promise state is whether the promise resolves or rejects. If you're using the `.then` approach to working with promises, you can supply a second callback function to handle the error case:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(status => {
    // If it gets to here, the promise resolved
    console.log(status);
  }, error => {
    // If it gets to here, the promise rejected
    console.log(error);
  });

// Or, equivalently:
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(status => {
    console.log(status);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

If you're using async/await, then you handle the error case with a try/catch

```
async someFunction() {
  try {
    const status = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    // If it gets to here, the promise resolved
    console.log(status);
  } catch (error) {
    // If it gets to here, the promise rejected
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```