# How to force an update from inside mapStateToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm talking about the `mapStateToProps` argument of [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

One of my components has a property called `rules` which is an array of functions. In `mapStateToProps` I invoke those rules, passing in the current state. The rules either return an error message or `true` if there is no error. I put these error messages into a new prop so that the final component receives an array of error messages instead of an array of functions.

So far this has been working great, but now I want to add support for asynchronous rules. My plan right now is that whenever a rule returns a Promise instead of an error string, I will push a message like "Checking..." into the array of error messages instead, but once the promise is settled I need to "refresh" this array and insert the resolved message.

I figure if I can [force an update](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) then redux will have to call `mapStateToProps` again. In such a case, all the rules would be re-evaluated, but if I'm not careful I would receive a new Promise which would put right back to square one. *However,* if I memoize these rules then I can get back the same Promise instance as before, and then [check if](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30564159/65387) [it's settled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21489870/65387) and then put that value into my error array instead.

So now the only problem is figuring out how to get a reference to the component instance within the context of `mapStateToProps` which only has access to the current state and props.

Is there any way I can force a re-render once my Promise has resolved?

Alternatively, if I could `dispatch` an action when it's resolved, I could work with that as well.

Comment: I *think* this is doable with `connectAdvanced`. With that I can get access to the state, props and dispatch function all at once, which should give me enough power to trigger a refresh when the promises resolve.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in `mapState`.  The `mapState` function is intended to be totally synchronous.  If you need to do something async, trigger that outside of `mapState`, store some values in state, and update them with the results to force `mapState` to re-run.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do this outside of `mapStateToProps`. I need both the state and the props of the component to evaluate these rules. I can get the state in my reducer, but then I'm missing the props. Even if I sent all the props along with every action I dispatch, it wouldn't help because then I could only revalidate the field that triggered the action, but I have contingent fields that may change validity based on the value of other fields.

Comment: You'll need some kind of middleware to do what you're asking to. Redux-saga https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga or Redux Thunk https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk are popular

Comment: @AnilRedshift I don't think either of those libs help with the problem I described. I don't have access to `dispatch` where I need it, so a middleware that handles dispatched actions doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a stateful component? If you keep the results from your promises in the component's state, it will automatically re-render the component once the promises resolve.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux;
import Promise from 'promise';

class MyStatefulComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            messages: [] // initialize empty, or with the synchronous rules
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const setState = this.setState;
        const rules = this.props.rules; // rules contains a list of either evaluated rules or promises
        Promise.all(rules).then(results => {
            // this is executed once all the promises in rules have resolved
            // setState will trigger a re-render of this component
            setState({
                messages: [] // construct your array of messages here from the results
            });
        })
    }

    render() {
        // render your list of messages
        return <ul>
            {this.state.messages.map(message => <li>{message}</li>)}
        </ul>;
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state, ownProps) => ({
        rules: ownProps.rules.map(rule => rule(state))
    })
)(MyStatefulComponent);
```

Comment: I hadn't considered that! I'd have to work all that state into the HOC though; I'm building a wrapper for inputs and that's too much boilerplate to repeat. Also, I wouldn't be able to wrap stateless functional components anymore. But... I'll give this a whirl if my plan doesn't work out, thanks for the idea!